# find multiple elements by id

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to find multiple elements by their respective ids
The elements are named

> dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-X

with X being the number of elements, it could be:

```
dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-0
dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-1
dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-2
...
dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-10
```

and the list goes on.
I've tried already this code:

```
pricesToFind = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-']")
```

without any success, the results always return NULL even if they really exist

piece of HTML to help:

```
<input _ngcontent-ihk-c34="" autocomplete="off" class="lib-input" maxlength="11" type="text" id="dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-variation-0">
```

the input name is randomly generated by javascript, so it's useless to scrape it via input name

Comment: Add you whole code, add target url and the element you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [contains](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html#1) or [starts-with](https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html#6)?

`pricesToFind = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@id,'dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-')]")`

`pricesToFind = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[starts-with(@id,'dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-')]")`

Comment: Code to work with your solution, since it's a list and its not possible to interact with them
```for pricesCounter in pricesToFind:
        pricesCounter.click()```

Comment: Yes, it was expected that it is the list. I thought you were aware of this as soon as you were using `find_elements_by_xpath` :)

Answer (score 1):

I personally have never used Selenium a lot, but I *hypothetically* know how to do this. I would use a while loop, and then run it over and over again. (Just letting you know, I have no way to actually test this, as I couldn't find any elements in any website that have those same conditions)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("somerandomwebsitehere.com/index.html")

a = 1
while a <= 100:
   element = browser.find_element(By.ID, "dcm-reservation-limit-multiple-input-generic-" + str(a))
   # Do whatever you want to the element
   a = int(a) + 1
```

Hopefully this helps. I make no guarantees that this code will work, but now you have an idea on how to make this happen.

Comment: You can also put all the elements into an array if you want; just search it up on Google.

Comment: Good solution, I don't have enough reputation to upvote it but you should be aware that your solution would break the code so if you want to use this loop, you should implement an error handler to avoid python from crashing with Selenium error of not finding enough elements for the loop

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Like I said, I have no way to test this, but I never thought of that.